# No sound from zoom conference

Tags: sound, zoom-meeting

I am using Ubuntu version 16. I m able to hear sound from browser and Youtube videos. But I use [zoom conference](https://www.zoom.us/), I m not able to hear any sound from laptop. Is it because on Ubuntu, I have to set the sound preferences for every application that I have to install ? Please consider and help me with this.

Comment: I opened an issue with Zoom here:
https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/requests/155803?flash_digest=99c193f374d8ae7f8bbf233f75c84708df838eb9

Comment: If your audio is bluetooth headphones it may need to be connected before starting zoom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gosom, @user4654: Looks like the Zoom people fixed it after I sent them a ticket. This fix works great for me!

Your request (#155803) has been updated. Reply to this email or follow the link below:
http://support.zoom.us/hc/requests/155803

Travis Tyler, Sep 6, 07:09 PDT:

Hi Alan,

We have a new version available at https://zoom.us/download/?os=linux for version # 2.0.63547.0830 .

Can you please update and see if this resolves your issue?

Thanks
Travis

Zoom Support Agent

Comment: So, basically, the answer is to update the software?

Comment: @ThomasWard - yes, that's the solution. I gather they didn't know about the problem until I reported it - and then they solved it in a week. I gotta say I was impressed by their support!

Comment: I see the problem is from 3 years ago, but I had this same issue today using the latest software and Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: In my case, I had to specifically enable audio after having joined the conference via the "Join Audio" button. A bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: In my case, the test speaker button is greyed out, so I don't think they are able to detect our speakers.

Comment: does not work on ubuntu 20.04, fresh install and it sucks when a fresh install app does not work as expected

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 19.10 and Zoom 5.4.0.53268.1025. The audio output volume was set to the minimum and the audio output device was incorrect in the call settings (accessible via the call properties button on the top left corner). After I changed both settings, the audio output worked fine.

Comment: Had the same problem with Zoom 5.10.4.2845. Installing 5.10.7.3311 seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 12):

1. Click on up arrow button on the right side of Unmute button (Unmute button on lower left) while you are on zoom meeting.
2. Click on Audio Settings
3. Increase output volume to maximum (by default it is set to minimum)

These steps solved the stated problem on both of my Ubuntu OS

Answer (score 11):

In case of **Ubuntu 20.04**, choose your actual device instead of the default Built-in Audio Analog Stereo.

Here's the screenshot of that window:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another situation that can occur here is that it picks the wrong audio device. In my case literally all applications just use the currently selected default audio device. Under Ubuntu 20.04 at least, Zoom just picks one at random, in this case the HDMI output to my monitor instead of my actual sound card.

There is no settings pane or anything else to configure it seems, so:

1. Click on the up arrow on the right side of the unmute button in the bottom left
2. Click the correct sound card

Comment: There is a settings pane. Settings -> Audio.